# UpSampling2D throwing error with keyword 'interpolation'

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm getting a weird error when I try to create a network using an upsampling layer, when I manually set the interpolate keyword to bilinear. 
If I leave it out, and go with the default of 'nearest neighbour; it works fine.
Does anyone know what's up?

Code for model. Error is thrown at layer 'up1'

```
def build_model(self):

    chnl4_input = Input(shape=(368, 256, 4))
    chnl3_input = Input(shape=(736, 512, 3))

    conv1 = Conv2D(26, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(chnl4_input)
    conv2 = Conv2D(26, self.kernel_size, strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)

    conv5 = Conv2D(64, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    conv6 = Conv2D(64, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

    up1 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation='bilinear')(conv6), conv1], axis=-1)
    conv7 = Conv2D(64, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(up1)

    conv8 = Conv2D(64, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)
    conv9 = Conv2D(64, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv8)

    conv11 = Conv2D(64, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv9)
    conv12 = Conv2D(64, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv11)

    up3 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation='bilinear')(conv12), chnl3_input], axis=-1)
    conv13 = Conv2D(67, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(up3)

    conv14 = Conv2D(67, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv13)
    conv15 = Conv2D(32, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv14)
    conv16 = Conv2D(3, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv15)

    out = conv16

    self.model = Model(inputs=[chnl4_input, chnl3_input], outputs=[out])

    self.model.compile(optimizer=self.optimizer_func, loss=self.loss_func)
    self.model.name = 'UNET'

    return self.modele here
```

Error : TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'interpolation')

```
 ~/MastersWork/Fergal/Scripts/models.py in build_model(self)
     29         conv6 = Conv2D(64, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)
     30 
---> 31         up1 = concatenate([UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2), interpolation='bilinear')(conv6), conv1], axis=-1)
     32         conv7 = Conv2D(64, self.kernel_size, activation='relu', padding='same')(up1)
     33 

~/anaconda3/envs/rhys_tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name +
     90                               '` call to the Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/anaconda3/envs/rhys_tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py in __init__(self, size, data_format, **kwargs)
   1804     @interfaces.legacy_upsampling2d_support
   1805     def __init__(self, size=(2, 2), data_format=None, **kwargs):
-> 1806         super(UpSampling2D, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   1807         self.data_format = conv_utils.normalize_data_format(data_format)
   1808         self.size = conv_utils.normalize_tuple(size, 2, 'size')

~/anaconda3/envs/rhys_tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
    291         for kwarg in kwargs:
    292             if kwarg not in allowed_kwargs:
--> 293                 raise TypeError('Keyword argument not understood:', kwarg)
    294         name = kwargs.get('name')
    295         if not name:
```

For reference, the Keras page regarding upSampling2D
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/UpSampling2D

Comment: Have you checked, that you use the newest version of tensorflow/keras?

Comment: Hey, yeah. I was running the tf nightly build from Monday just gone (02/25), but I also went back to tf1.9 and I'm seeing the same error.
Edit, also 1.12. It seems odd to me that no one would have noticed this for so long, so possibly an issue in my environment?

Comment: I am on version of `2.2.2` of Keras and `1.9.0` of Tensorflow. I am having the same issue. Maybe a bug

Comment: Interesting. In that case I'll file an issue on the keras GitHub. Cheers

Comment: Same issue with Tensorflow 1.12.0 but Keras 2.2.4 works as described in the documentation.

Comment: Ah thanks! That'll sort me out for now!

Comment: Please post the full error trace.

Comment: Running in Jupyter. Trace posted I think

Answer (score 1):

```
def bilinear_upsameple(tensor, size):
    y = tf.image.resize_bilinear(images=tensor, size=size)
    return y
dims = K.int_shape(input_tensor)
y_scaled = Lambda(lambda x : bilinear_upsameple(tensor=x, size=(dims[1]*scale, dims[2]*scale)))(input_tensor)
```

here is a work around for bilinear upsampling, using lambda layer and tf.image.resize_bilinear
works fine on tf 1.12.0